# Visual recognition mouse-click automation utility?

Tags: macos, testing, automation, automated-tests, utilities

Is anybody aware of any kind of a simple MacOSX utility that can take a given image and find whether the image is on the screen (perhaps with a certain variance threshold) and then position the mouse and/or click on the area which matches the image?  Please don't respond about how this is a terrible idea and shouldn't be done.  This is an important task for testing and cannot be easily accomplished by triggering events or the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project SIKULI:

"Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots). Sikuli includes Sikuli Script, a visual scripting API for Jython, and Sikuli IDE, an integrated development environment for writing visual scripts with screenshots easily. Sikuli Script automates anything you see on the screen without internal API's support. You can programmatically control a web page, a Windows/Linux/Mac OS X desktop application, or even an iphone or android application running in a simulator or via VNC."

www.sikuli.org

Free for Mac OS X

Comment: I discovered SIKULI shortly after writing this question, and it has indeed been my solution to date.